# *$G$-invariant* symmetric bilinear form & $G'=\Bbb Z_2\times\Bbb Z_2$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory

I got a problem with the last point

[image]

I solved all the points, from (a) to (h), but I have no idea how to solve (i): how can I associate a bilinear form to a represtation? What is a *$G$-invariant* bilinear form? I think we are dealing with something like
$$
f:V\times V\to\Bbb C
$$
Such that $f(g.v,w)=f(v,g.w)$ or maybe $f(g.v,g.w)=f(v,w)$ for every $g\in G, v\in V, w\in W$, but is one of these two right? If not how can I solve this?

**EDIT**: I realized I didn't done correctly the (c) point: in previous points we get $|[G,G]|=4$, thus $[G,G]$ is $\Bbb Z_4$ the cyclic of order $4$ or $\Bbb Z_2\times\Bbb Z_2$; I must show that $[G,G]$ is NOT the cylic one. If so, $[G,G]=\langle g\rangle=\{1,g,g^2,g^3\}$; how can I get a contradiction if I assume $[G,G]$ contains an element of order $4$?

Answer (score 2):

This is what a $G$-invariant bilinear form is: Let $f$ be a $G$-invariant bilinear form. Then $f(vg,wg)=f(v,w)$ for all $g\in G$. I'm going to work on a solution and post back.